# Mocking one function inside of a module, called from inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a function inside a utils module.

In my Home component, I have

```
import { ImageUtils } from "../utils";

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    ImageUtils.preloadImages(() => {
      setIsloading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>1 sec...</p>
      ) : (
        <AgamaApp />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In "../utils", I have:

```
export { default as ScreenUtils } from "./screen_utils";
export { default as DateUtils } from "./date_utils";
export { default as LocalStorageUtils } from "./localstorage_utils";
export { default as ImageUtils } from "./image_utils";
```

And in "utils/image_utils.ts" I have:

```
import images from "../shared/images";

const preloadImages = (onComplete: () => void) => {
  Promise.all(
    images.map((image) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = image.path;
        img.onload = () => {
          resolve(undefined);
        };
        img.onerror = () => reject(new Error("Couldn't load image"));
      });
    })
  ).then(onComplete);
};

export default {
  preloadImages,
};
```

In my test file, if I do:

```
import { ImageUtils } from "../utils";

ImageUtils.preloadImages = jest.fn((onComplete) => {
  console.log("function was called");
  onComplete();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  render(<App />);
});

test("drawer slides open when hamburger menu clicked", async () => { ... });
```

the function never gets called. But if I do

```
import { ImageUtils } from "../utils";

ImageUtils.preloadImages = (onComplete) => {
  console.log("function was called");
  onComplete();
};

beforeEach(() => {
  render(<App />);
});

test("drawer slides open when hamburger menu clicked", async () => { ... });
```

everything works fine.

How best can I resolve this and use Jest the way it's supposed to here?

Comment: Are you importing `preloadImages` in your test?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I'm importing ImageUtils from "../utils", but not preloadImages. I'm unaware if there's a way to import that function directly.

Comment: Can you try `jest.mock("../utils");` after the `import` statement and then `ImageUtils.preloadImages,mockImplementation(() => console.log("called"));`

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Thanks for the suggestion! `ImageUtils.preloadImages.mockImplementation(() => console.log("called"));` causes a TypeScript error: `Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '(onComplete: () => void) => void'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Can you share your full code somewhere, maybe in pastebin. You might have done something incorrectly.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Here's the pastebin, let me know if you'd like any other files: https://pastebin.com/yUFhACKz

Comment: Are all the tests failing? And can you share live example using codesandbox, then I would be able to do run the code as well

Comment: Is it a TypeScript specific error? Can you ignore the TypeScript error and run?